# Can't instantiate usbmanager inside the Jar thats created

Tags: java, android, jar, usbserial, ftdi

I am trying to use usbmanager inside a library i create.

In my library I have:

```
public class usb_manager extends Service{

   private UsbManager myUsbManager;

        public usb_manager(){
          myUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        }
   }
...
}
```

then i am trying to call the constructor in another java file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public usb_manager testusb = new usb_manager();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
 ...
}
```

the app crashes when it starts.

but if i change the code in my library to, (ie, move the initialization of usbmanager to the activity):

```
public class usb_manager extends Service{

   private UsbManager myUsbManager;

        public usb_manager(UsbManager in){
          mUsbManager = in;
        }     
...
}
```

and in MainActivity of my program:

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  public usb_manager testusb; = new usb_manager();
  private UsbManager myUsbManager;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           myUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            testusb = new usb_manager(myUsbManager);

 }
 ...
 }
```

it works.

can anyone tell me what is the problem with using
    myUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

inside the library file.

Comment: What's the crash? Have you specified `com.android.future.usb.accessory` for the library?

Comment: in my library i have 
     `import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;`
     `import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `getSystemService()` returns `null` in constructor since `Context` is not initalized. Override `onCreate()` in your `usb_manager` service and assign `myUsbManager` there.
And don't call service constructor in `Activity` use `startService()` instead.

See this [services tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Yes... but also instantiate the Service properly, **not** by calling it's constructor.

Comment: Right. I've overlooked that constructor call. Answer updated.

Comment: ok i see what happend, let me work on it and i will update you guys later, thanks